# Add My SQL data source in VIsual Studio express 2013

Tags: mysql, datasource

I already install this two requirement:
1-Connector/Net 6.8.1 beta or higher version to check the Connector/Net & Entity Framework features. (download at: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ on the development releases).
2-https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1.msi

But still not sure why the data source still not appear in the option. Anyone have idea why? Please advise.

[image]

BTW I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013.

Answer (score 3):

That's because Visual Studio Express does not allow you to install extensions. This is one of the limitations of the Express edition. You need to add everything MySQL related manually.

This is also stated [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio.html):

> MySQL for Visual Studio does not support Express versions of Microsoft development products, including the Visual Studio and the Microsoft Visual Web Developer.
>
> To use MySQL Connector/Net with an Express versions of Microsoft development products, use MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.4 or later, without installing the MySQL for Visual Studio.

That does *not* mean that you cannot use MySQL in the Express Edition. It just means that you don't get to use the nifty design-time tools ;-)

Comment: Really?so I need to install the older version MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.4? and uninstall the MySQL for Visual Studio?

Comment: I suggest you read the page I linked. Maybe that helps you. I'm not too much into MySQL and have rarely used it in a Windows environment, but if the docs says so... As I said, you can always use the latest Connector DLLs and do stuff manually.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do if you have access , create an access DB that use ODBC to link to the MySQL Server , and then import the access DB as a data source in VS Express.

That way you are Using Access as a middle man to handle the connection :

VS Express <--> Access DB <--> Mysql