# MySQL data source is not appearing in Visual studio 2010 express edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have installed MySQl connector for .Net 6.8.3 and MySQL for visual studio 1.1.1 in my machine. when I try to create ADO.Net Entity Data Model for Entity framework 6.0 i cannot see MySQl data source in the "Choose Data source" window.

I am wondering whether MySQL connector is even supported by vs2010 express.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express does not allow you to install extensions. So you will not "see" MySQl data source in the "Choose Data source" window. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472891/add-my-sql-data-source-in-visual-studio-express-2013).

I see you have used a VS 2012 tag. If this is professional edition or higher, I would suggest that if you are using Entity Framework 6, that you download and install MySQL connector 1.1.4. for use with v6.8.3. v1.1.4 fixed some bugs relating to EF 6.

You you can read about it [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/mysql_for_visual_studio_12) and download it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/).