# Visual Studio 2013 connection to local MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

Getting right to the point, I'm learning Visual Basic, and I want to connect Visual Studio 2013 Express to a local MySQL database that I have running on the default 3306 port.  For now I would be ecstatic just to have it show up in the explorer for me to play around and see what one can do with it.

**The Current State of Things:**

So, I went opened up the "Data Sources" sidebar and tried to set up a connection to the database:

[image]

The credentials and db name at the bottom are both correct, by the way.
Yet, "Test Connection" laughs in my face with this generic, unhelpful error:

[image]

So I do some Googling to figure out where I messed up my server's my.ini file. These are the only edits I've made from the default config:

- bind-address: 127.0.0.1
- skip-networking: true
- enable-named-pipe: true
- port: 3306
- socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
- skip-grant-tables

All in attempt to remove as many possible connection hindrances as I can, to the best of my knowledge. 
I made sure the server is running, restarted the service after every config change, and I can access the database from MySQL Workbench just fine. I'm at a loss :( so if you have an idea, lets hear it! :)

***If I left out anything useful, or if you need more info, I'll get it for you!***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472891/add-my-sql-data-source-in-visual-studio-express-2013 Since you say you're using VS 2013 Express, this may be relevant to you.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IJsE2wU.png   Thanks for the comment.  I read the page in that post, and from what I gather, VS Express shouldn't keep me from connecting to a MySQL database, I just won't be able to use the installer from MS.  I would have to use "MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.4 or later, without installing the MySQL for Visual Studio"  But I've already installed this connector when I installed MySQL, and I haven't installed the MS plugin he mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I just may have found the solution!
As I'm having the same problem; cannot connect to MySQL using an Express version of Visual Basic: the problem it self seems to be with MS licensing.

However I came across an announcement of Oracle MySQL saying with the new release of Visual Studio Community it would be possible to use MySQL to connect to a database.
I just finished my installation of Visual Studio Community 2013 and successfully created a connection a local database using MySQL.

You can download Visual Studio Community [Here:](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx)

Additionally you'd have to download and install MySQL for Visual Studio, download link [here:](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)

Seems there is no need to install a MySQL Connector.

I've seen multiple threads with this same question. Hopefully solved now.